# How to remove icon showing before launch screen on Appcelerator iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, appcelerator

I am updating an iOS ipad app in appcelerator (titanium alloy).  My only problem is that when I open the app it shows my icon image before it shows the launch/splash image. It wasn't doing this in the first version I created.  I want just the launch image to show.  At first it was only showing the icon and no launch image at all, so I changed this to false:
`<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>`
I'd rather supply my own images than use the storyboard feature anyway.
So now the launch image shows, but the icon is still there too.
 
I have the following files in app/assets/iphone
-Default-568@2x.png
-Default-667h@2x.png
-Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png
-Default-Landscape.png
-Default-Landscape@2x.png
-Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png
-Default-Portrait@2x.png
-Default-Portrait.png
-Default@2x.png
That's probably more than what I need, but don't think that should be a problem.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the app in the emulator and launch it again..

Comment: what do you mean by 'deleting it in the emulator'?  I've closed the emulator and did a clean and rebuild of the app and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I guess what Juan means is rapidly hitting Shift+Command+H twice on your keyboard with the simulator in focus, (better said: hold shift+command and hit H twice; or with menu Hardware -> Home)  to reach the 'home page'; there you can long-click on your installed  app icon to delete it. Then build again in order to re-install.

Comment: well, I made a little confusion with hitting twice: actually to get to the home page one time Shift+Command+H is enough. 

Hitting twice  let you open the 'task manager' with running apps (I did it too many times), my bad.

Comment: OK, marked as correct answer because this helped me figure it out.  I wasn't seeing it on the simulator just in the testflight version on my ipad.  So deleting from the simulator didn't help, but deleting the app from my ipad did work.  Yay!